# How To Unlink Image In Joomla "Articles-Newsflash" Module

Tags: hyperlink, joomla, module

I try since long time to automatically turn of the function, that every image of the "Articles-Newsflash" module doesn't get a link automatically. It's possibly to remove the  by hand for every image but I am searching for a final solution so that no new image gets a link.
Maybe someone issued the same problem before and has a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [layout overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla).